# Matroid representable over $\mathbb{R}$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

Does there exist a matroid that is representable over $\mathbb{R}$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}$?

In particular, can one give a positive answer using a nonrational polytope, i.e., a combinatorial polytope that cannot be realized as the convex hull of rational vertices?  (Such things do exist; see, e.g., p.94 of Grünbaum's *Convex Polytopes*.)  The vertex sets of the faces of a convex polytope certainly form the flats of a matroid, but it's not clear to me why the same matroid could not be realized by affine dependences of a set of points not in convex position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jeremy, on the very same page 94 you will find a "point and line configuration" called *Perles configuration* which when viewed as set ov vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ is a matroid that is realizable over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$ but not over $\Bbb Q$.  In [my book](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm) I even prove it (Ex 12.3) - sorry to make a plug, this is the only place with a proof I know.

Comment: (wipes egg off face)  Quite right.  Thanks, Igor.

Comment: This might be a better question: Is there a matroid that is representable over $\mathbb{R}$, but not over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Um, Jeremy, I think you should continue reading p.94, starting with "As a matter of fact..."  To clarify for those without a book, the answer is NO.  BTW, this is the reason Grünbaum won the Steele Prize: http://www.math.washington.edu/newsletter/2005/grunbaum.html